# react-nativ-camera -- Accessing the java files functionalities

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

Hiii
Using react-native-camera library module, can we get the live frames of the camera preview in JS. As the camera is opened each frame should be captured at the JS side in the form of byte array or base64 ??